# VBScript - skip and read lines in text file

Tags: vbscript, readline

Would you be able to help me figure out/make pretty my code? 
I have a file I need to edit and save some of it to next file. Saving is not an issue here, only editing.
I need to skip 2 lines and read next 30 or so to memory. Until now I've been using:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strMyDocs = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDesktop & "\folder\blabla.vbs", ForReading)

strText = objFile.SkipLine & objFile.SkipLine
strText = objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & 
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & 
vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine &_
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & 
vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & 
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine &_
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & 
vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & 
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine &_
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & 
vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & 
objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine & objFile.ReadLine
objFile.Close
...
```

As you can see it looks pretty lame, it does the job though.
I was able to find something to replace skilLine part:

```
For a = 1 to 30
If ((a =< 2) And (ObjFile.AtEndOfStream <> True)) Then
objFile.SkipLine
Do Until a = 30
objFile.ReadLine
Loop
Else    
objFile.Close
End If
```

but cannot find a way to read next 28lines. I tried a lot and it always reads 28 lines but starting with line 31, not 3.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way.

```
' Read all lines into an array...
a = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDesktop & "\folder\blabla.vbs", ForReading).ReadAll, vbCrLf)

' Start with the 3rd line and read 28 lines (if available)...
For i = 2 To 29
    If UBound(a) >= i Then strText = strText & a(i) & vbCrLf
Next
```

Comment: Works out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm trying to edit text held in strText and replace few things in it.
    strNewText = Replace (strText,"INC",input )
    strNewText = Replace (strText,"'","")
It does replace ' with "blank" but swapping INC into input value does not.
Any clues?

Comment: `Replace()` is case-sensitive by default. Is `"INC"` in uppercase in your text string? You can use the `vbTextCompare` param to do a case-insensitive replacement.

Comment: it's strange. Using my previous, lame method it all worked well and INC got changed into input and ' into "". Now it does not.
I changed order from INC and ' to ' and INC and now I see only the second `Replace()` kicks in. Why?

Comment: maybe sth to do with method you proposed?

Comment: I was able to bypass it by using one more strNewtext.

`strNewText = Replace(strText,"'","")
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText,"INC",input )`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  Note the addition of the `Do Until` loop.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strMyDocs = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDesktop & "\folder\blabla.vbs", ForReading)
objfile.SkipLine
objfile.SkipLine
Dim strText

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    If(Len(strText) > 0) Then strText = strText & vbNewLine
    strText = strText & objFile.ReadLine
Loop

objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

This will read a line if the `rowcount` is greater than 2 or less than 30, else it will skip the line, you can then do something with that line in `strText`

```
rowcount = 1

Do While NOT objFile.AtEndOfStream

    if((rowcount > 2) And (rowcount < 30))Then

        strText = objTextFile.Readline
        'or strText = strText & vbCrLf & objTextFile.Readline

    Else

        strText = objTextFile.SkipLine 


    End If
rowcount = rowcount + 1
Loop
```