# Most performant way of inserting 3GB .tsv into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

What's the most performant way of inserting a 3GB `.tsv` into SQL Server?

I do not know the column names, whenever I try to preview it, takes forever...

If it is easier to first create the table in SQL Server and then insert the `.tsv`? I could contact the provider of the `.tsv` and find out the exact column names.

Comment: You can't talk about performance when you don't even know the schema.  Doesn't the file have a header row? Anyway, SQL Server's SSIS works with most flat files and can even make a pretty decent guess at column types. It's the infrastructure hidden behind the `Import Data` wizard. The wizard can also create the table for you.

Comment: Performance will depend on your hardware and the table schema. There's not much point for example in using partitioning for example if you have a single disk. Make sure you drop/disable any indexes before starting the load and rebuild them afterwards.

Comment: You can use Windows `more` command to print the first 35 or so lines (1 CMD screen-full) of the file. For example, in CMD type: `more filename.tsv`

Answer (score 1):

I would think that your best bet is to extract a set number of lines and use that to estimate some broad, catch-all columns and create a table you can load into for analysis of the complete dataset.

You could do this with a small script file like those discussed here:
[VBScript - skip and read lines in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133276/vbscript-skip-and-read-lines-in-text-file)

Once you have an understanding of your data structure, in my experience the fastest way to load data into SQL Server - though far from the most convenient - is the Bulk Copy Program Utility, or BCP:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The faster way to insert data into SQLServer is using Bulk Insert:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx
But you need to know data schema.

Comment: SSIS is using Bulk Insert. The OP mentions previewing which probably means that SSIS or the Import Wizard is used